# Updating Value in Series Based on Another Series with condition

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two series  sr1 and sr2:

```
sr1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
sr2 = pd.Series([6, 0, 0, 4 ,9])
```

I want to update series 1 i.e sr1 from sr2. If sr2 is 0 then same value should be updated in sr1 for same index. I want below output :

```
       sr1

    0   1
    1   0
    2   0
    3   4
    4   5
```

Comment: Did you mean to construct `df1` this way, or did you mean `pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5], name='A')`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: I want to update series 1 i.e df1 from df2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use series, You can use the following code:

```
sr1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) 
sr2 = pd.Series([6, 0, 0, 4 ,9])
sr1=sr1.mask(sr2==0,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `mask`

```
df1=df1.mask(df2.A==0,0)
   A
0  1
1  0
2  0
3  4
4  5
```

Comment: `Array conditional must be same shape as self` i get this error

Comment: @MohammadNazari df1 and df2 have the same length  ?

Comment: Your code was correct. in question df1 is a pd.Series